# Linking c++ with python

Tags: python, c++

I have made a chatbot in c++ using gcc compiler which uses basic file handling operations to handle user queries but now I wanted to upgrade the same.For this I thought of linking my code to internet,opening windows programs and providing it a GUI interphase.As I have recently learned python and I know that developing a GUI and connecting code to internet is much easier than it was in c++.So I thought of linking my c++ code with python.How can I do it so that the basic code remains same but i link it to internet using python.I searched  and found out cpython,py++ and swig but as I am new I don't know much.Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "basic" file handling, you might easily accomplish this with the python standard libary module `subprocess`. Does you chatbot just read and write to stdin and stdout?

Comment: Yes it does do this

Answer (score 0):

You may need to write your python wrapper for the c++ code. You can use [boost::python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html) for this

Comment: Is it best to use boost or something else.From where would I get boost.

Comment: @user9471930 download boost from [here](http://www.boost.org/users/download/). You may need to build it for your system.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution, given your chatbot read/writes to stdin/stdout, is to use the `subprocess` module as it requires the least amount of fuss. Here you will start your chatbot in a separate process and then use it as if from a terminal.

Below is a basic implementation of something that could talk to your C++ chatbot (it just uses `cat` to echo input as an example). Its `say` method is blocking and assumes exactly one line of output for each line of input. It will get into trouble if your chatbox has multi-line responses.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import io

CMD = 'cat'

class Chatbot:
    def __init__(self):
        self._chatbot_proc = Popen(CMD, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
        # You may wish to add encoding='ascii' to the TextIOWrapper constructor
        # if your chatbot is not UTF-aware.
        self._input = io.TextIOWrapper(self._chatbot_proc.stdin, line_buffering=True)
        self._output = io.TextIOWrapper(self._chatbot_proc.stdout)

    def close(self):
        self._input.close()
        self._output.close()
        self._chatbot_proc.close()

    def say(self, request):
        assert '\n' not in request
        self._input.write(request)
        self._input.write('\n')
        return self._output.readline().rstrip()

def main():
    chatbot = Chatbot()
    try:
        while True:
            user_input = input()
            print('sending:', repr(user_input))
            chatbot_response = chatbot.say(user_input)
            print('chatbot said:', repr(chatbot_response))
    except Exception:
        chatbot.close()
        raise

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```